# Как сделать анонимную регистрацию в django_rest_framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Можно ли сделать анонимную регистрацию пользователя при POST запросе, чтобы после запроса создавалась модель User с рандомным логином и паролем ?

Answer (score 0):

а зачем вам оно? Может и не нужно это? Но впрочем вот

```
import random
import string
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def createRandomUser():
    uname = 'user_'+''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(6))
    upass = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()_') for _ in range(10))   
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=uname, password=upass)
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Нужно для регистрации пользователей, чтобы при регистрации пользователь передавал ничего не передавал, но при этом создавалась модель User, но со случайным логином и паролем

Comment: Таблицу пользователей загадите. лучше завести одну учетку и за анонимов делать автологин под этим пользователем